# Compute Gas Volume Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I'm completely lost on this python homework question the problem is Define a function compute_gas_volume that returns the volume of a gas given parameters pressure, temperature, and moles. Use the gas equation PV = nRT, where P is pressure in Pascals, V is volume in cubic meters, n is number of moles, R is the gas constant 8.3144621 ( J / (mol*K)), and T is temperature in Kelvin.

The starter code is

```
gas_const = 8.3144621
def compute_gas_volume((gas_pressure,,gas_temperature,gas_moles):

    gas_pressure = 100.0
    gas_moles = 1.0
    gas_temperature = 273.0
    gas_volume = 0.0
    gas_volume = compute_gas_volume(gas_pressure, gas_temperature, gas_moles)
print('Gas volume:', gas_volume, 'm^3')
```

can anyone help me with the question?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You didn't even want to put in the effort to lowercase the first letter of the prompt, or format it? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Please see [this article](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) for an explanation of how to ask homework questions.

Answer (score 3):

As the law is PV = nRT, volume can be simply computed as V= nRT/P, hence:

```
GAS_CONST = 8.3144621
def compute_gas_volume(gas_pressure, gas_temperature, gas_moles):
    return gas_moles * GAS_CONST * gas_temperature / gas_pressure
```

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange it to equal V:

```
double ComputeGasVolume (double gasPressure, double gasTemperature, double gasMoles) {
   double gasVolume = ((gasMoles * GAS_CONST) * gasTemperature) / gasPressure;

   return gasVolume;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

return(moles * gas_const * temperature / pressure)

This is the correct formula.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).